# MVC in JSP - standard approach

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a dummy project of Online Book Ordering System to practice JSP. Am trying to follow MVC in it.

By definition, in MVC any changes in model must not need any changes in View/Controller.

In Model, I created Customer class (having customer attribute and its getter-setters) and CustomerCollection class (which performs CRUD on customer data)

In Controller, I have a Controller servlet which invokes CustomerCollection, accesses Customer data and adds the list of customers as an attribute of request.

In view, I have JSP which accesses the list of custoemers added by controller and displays it in the page as follows:

```
<table id="customerTable">
                <tr id="customerTableHeaderRow">
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Phone number</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                </tr>
                <%                  
                    for(Customer customer: customers)                        
                    {  
                %>
                <tr class="customerTableRow">
                    <td><%= customer.getId() %></td>
                    <td><%= customer.getFirstName() %></td>
                    <td><%= customer.getLastName() %></td>
                    <td><%= customer.getAddress() %></td>
                    <td><%= customer.getPhoneNumber() %></td>
                    <td><%= customer.getGender() %></td>                    
                </tr>   
                <%      
                    }
                %>
 </table>
```

However now I believe that when I make any changes to my database, like adding any column to a customers table, I have to modify for loop in view to display the content of that column too which is not good.

So whats wrong here? Am doing it wrong? Or is there **any standard way to do the same**?

Comment: Do you have any link supporting this claim - "any changes in model must not need any changes in View/Controller.". It seems incorrect to me.

Comment: well ideally, otherwise it will be a defeat of MVC's very purpose

Comment: IMHO, as per MVC you should have clear separation between your Model, View and Controller and each of them should do its own job, but it does not say any change in Model should not change view. You will have to make changes in View if you change the Model!

Comment: umm ohkay but any comment on whether am implementing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC approach, the JSP file should not contain any line of Java code, you should be using JSTL and the servlet class should not contain any JDBC code, you should use DAO. So basically you are implementing it right, just need to make few changes as below.

By naming convention your CustomerCollection should be CustomerDAO.
Replace Scriptlets with JSTL and EL.

Customes in jsp can be accessed as below.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<table>
<c:forEach items="${customers}" var="customer">
    <tr>
        <td>${customer.firstName}</td> - access all your attributes this way
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: awesome points: +1 for CustoemrDAO; +1 for use JSTL/EL; +1 for code;

Comment: but still JSP need to be modified if model changes?